# Java Path Set Issue

Tags: java, windows-server-2008, path, environment-variables

I am using win server 2008, Trying to set java path. I set it in both user variables and system variables. yet, I couldn't access java.

[image: Not Working]

But when I check in java installed path It is working fine

[image: Working]

These are my system path variables. Can anyone help me.

[image: java home]

[image: path]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Need to Set Classpath too as follows

Variable name = classpath and Variable Value =

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/Javajdk1.7.0_21/lib
```

check [this](http://www.abodeqa.com/2012/08/11/how-to-set-path/) for reference